# Embedding an Access database in SharePoint?

Tags: 2013, excel, microsoft-access

I have a client who would like me to embed an access database from another location (document library) to a SharePoint page in an editable format. Similar to how you can add the "Excel Web Access" web part and display an editable excel document.

I have tried to use the "Access Web App" under the apps, but this sends out an error. I am under the assumption that this is simply not a function that works at my current business location.

Are there any web parts of functions I could utilize to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK their is no such OOTB web part which will give you the editable Access database. But if you configure the Access Services 2013 then you can use Access web app

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748634(v=office.15).aspx

You can also check this, i dont know if it write back or not:
http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2013/08/08/how-to-add-an-access-2013-database-to-a-sharepoint-2013-list.aspx